# Suffix tries vs dynamic programming for string algorithms

Tags: string, algorithm, data-structures, tree, dynamic-programming

It seems that many difficult string algorithms can be solved both using suffix tries(trees) and Dynamic Programming.
But I am not sure which approach is best to use and when.
Additionally which approach is better to master on the specific area of algorithms and have it in your arsenal in the area of job interviews? I assume it would be the one that would be used more frequently by a programmer in any task or something like that?
This is more of which algorithmic technique is more useful to master as most frequent to use in your job than simply comparing asymptotic notations

Comment: You can't say one algorithm is better than the other generally. Sometimes, "easy to code" and "work with the input limit" makes a less general algorithm better than a "hard to code", "high hidden constant", "work best with large input". You should pick up algorithm relevant to your area of work rather than study all of them.

Comment: @nhahtdh:Is it an algorithm comparison here?Or is it an algorithm design technique/paradigm comparison?

Comment: Cratylus, shouldn't you be the one to tell us that? It's your question after all, not nhanhtdh's.

Answer (score 2):

Think of a problem requiring the [Lexicographically nth substring of a given string](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/find-strings) : A suffix array is just what you need...and it is easy to learn the bare essentials for solving most problems involving suffix arrays..
On the other hand DP is an algorithmic technique..MASTER IT and you will be able to solve a HUGE number of problems..not only strings.
For an interview though i will take DP anyday...for interviewers, a DP problem lets them make it knotty that is almost impossible to solve without DP (within given constraints) but the solution would mean that you give them a basic recursion and how DP helps you solve it.If it were a suffix-array-only-problem that would mean that they are assessing you over a single data structure( easy once learned) rather than an **more general technique which requires mastery.**

**PS**: I had put off learning DP until recently when i got fed up trying to solve problems (that require DP ) using any advanced data structures and would invariably fail ( Case in point : [UVA 1394](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14462401/uva-1394-and-there-was-one-algorithm) -- simple problem now that i know how to solve it using DP but instead went on to study segment trees and achieved a O(nlgn) whereas DP gave me O(n). So final advice : if one hasn't studied DP drop everything else and go for it.

Comment: That is just a simple Josephus problem... It is not worth calling DP.

Comment: i agree it is recursion with memoization but was making a point about the way one thinks if not accustomed to DP and recursions in large...Trying to solve it using some unheard of data structure proved to be futile..

Comment: If you read the Wikipedia article, it looks more like a math problem rather than a DP problem. Anyway, there are tricks to solving the "easy" (prescribed/obvious) or "medium" (parameters can be derived from problem statement) DP problems.

Comment: I had read recently that DP problems are too hard to be used to evaluate a candidate (even a good programmer may go badly on one) and are rarely used in interviews.Seems this statement is incorrect eh?

Comment: identifying a problem to be solvable by dp itself requires practice and intuition...see this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14412112/google-interview-find-the-maximum-sum-of-a-polygon

Comment: @enjay:`simple problem now that i know how to solve it using DP` How did you study DP?Do you have some good references?

Answer (score 1):

honestly, for job interview, no suffix tree is needed. that's too difficult and beyond the scope. however, DP is widely used in interviews for some famous companies like google and facebook.

suffix tree has limitation for solving problems compared with DP. usually it is used to solve string related problems. but DP can solve many different areas.

Comment: So your point is that in general DP is more useful since it covers wider range of problems.Spefically for string related problems do you change your answer or not?

Comment: yes, but for string related problems, suffix tree is a good choice and alternation

Comment: If `for string related problems, suffix tree is a good choice and alternation` then why do you say `no suffix tree is needed. that's too difficult and beyond the scope` if it is an important data structure

Comment: 1st, u r almost impossible to be asked to write a suffix tree code during the interview. 2nd, suffix tree can be used to solve string related problems, but this is not the only choice. u can use suffix array, DP etc to achieve the same goal. however, DP is irreplacable. usually, in the interview, u r expected to write code for DP, but u just need to mention that "this problem can also be solved by suffix tree", and give some simple explanation. that's enough, no coding is needed.